# Android Broadcast receiver to read data from external health device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am creating a blood pressure monitoring app.

I successfully connect to the device via bluetooth and send a command to start measuring blood pressure. But I face difficulty in reading the response from the device. I want to create a broadcast receiver because the device takes almost 30 sec to 1 min to calculate blood pressure.

How can I register the broadcast with the app and read the data?

Comment: How are you reading data from the device? Over bluetooth?

Comment: So, as I can understand you send the command to the external device and you have no event back when it's done. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I did not known when It done the process and send back to android phone over blue tooth.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to get an event back from your external device. It's a matter of how your device works. If it provides a way to inform you that it has finished. My suggestion is to poll over it. You check after 30 minutes if it has ended his calculation

Comment: It just take max 1 minute time.

Comment: Sorry, 30 seconds then. After that you could check if it's finished. But I don't really know how to do that, since I don't know how your external device works